# Scale_fill_brewer in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use scale_fill_brewer in a barplot(geom_bar), but I am having always the same error that I don't understand.
Here, that would be my code:

```
LW25_cwt <-data.frame(
    "name"=c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW","C","A","U"),
    "days/winter"=c(7.07,3.6,8.4,5.5,10.5,6.2,7,4,54,43,10)) 
LW10_cwt <-data.frame(
    "name"=c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW","C","A","U"),
    "days/winter"=c(2.07,1.6,3.4,6.5,11,6.7,7.2,10,51,42,4))


  LW25_cwt$LWdays <- "LW25"
   LW10_cwt$LWdays <- "LW10"
   sp=rbind(LW25_cwt,LW10_cwt)


   c2 <- ggplot(sp, aes(y=days.winter,x=name, fill=LWdays)) + 
        ggtitle("LoW-Wind days (1961-2000)") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=1,face="bold", color="black",
        size=17,vjust=2.5))+     
        ylab('days/year') +  xlab('CWTs Types') +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 
   c2 <- c2 + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

If I don't use scale_fill_brewer, it perfectly works, but if I use it I have this:

Error in object[seq_len(ile)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In class(y) <- class(x) :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("brewer", "discrete", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object
2: In class(y) <- class(x) :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("brewer", "discrete", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object
```

Any idea?? I have been looking it, but unfortunately I have not found the solution.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. I get an error when running your code on my computer: `object 'LW25_cwt' not found`. Please edit your question to include a small sample dataset that allows me to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi,

yes, sorry,these are LW25 and LW10 (two data frames): 
 LW25 <-data.frame("name"=c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW","C","A","U"),"days/winter"=c(7.07,3.6,8.4,5.5,10.5,6.2,7,4,54,43,10))
 LW10 <-data.frame("name"=c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW","C","A","U"),"days/winter"=c(2.07,1.6,3.4,6.5,11,6.7,7.2,10,51,42,4))

I hope you can help with this, I always have the same warning!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: added the data to your question (should have been LW25_cwt, not LW_25). The code runs for me without any problems. Try updating your ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to convert `sp$LWdays` explicitly to a factor rather than a character vector. `sp$LWdays <- factor(sp$LWdays)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately my problem continues. I changed into a factor sp$LWdays, but I still have this warning. I don't know what the problem is<  I also checked my version and I am using: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
       Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately my problem continues. I changed into a factor sp$LWdays, but I still have this warning. I don't know what the problem is<  I also checked my version and I am using: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
       Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit), any helps will be appreciated!